# Img src VS CSS Background Image No Intrinsic Dimensions

Tags: html, css

I've got a markdown with HTML built inside and I need to change the following:

```
<img src="..." />
```

Into

```
<img class="image" /> // Could also be a div, doesn't matter
```

And give it a background-image CSS style instead (this is due to webpack bundling and the fact I have no imports and variables in `.md` files)

Problem is that the first option loads the image properly without having to specify height/width, and the 2nd approach shows nothing unless I specify height/width.

[Fiddle demonstrating issue](https://jsfiddle.net/2yxfr7Ly/)

Why is this, and is there a way to bypass this without specifying height/width for every such occurence?

Comment: Why? Because setting the background image does only that, and if the element has no content or defined dimensions, then it collapses accordingly and the background can't be seen as it has no size.

Comment: @j08691 Makes sense. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: Is there any way around what? Having an empty element (not `<img src="..." />`) with no dimensions and no content show the background image? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is calculate the proportion of the `img` and then use the value for `padding` and `cover` to fit that:

As an example if the image is `1:1` proportion:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/3Zh2iqf.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice sorcery!

Comment: @OmriAharon glad to help U