# CSS crop a image to a square

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to crop a image with a random size to a square aspect ratio. I just wanna use CSS and want it to be responsive and adapt the witdth and height automatically.

The css clip function does not work with percentages. (I'm using bootstrap grid)

Are there any other methods?

Thanks for your help and hints

Comment: Please add your code, there are few ways to aproach your issue but without seen your markup and css it's like shoot to the sky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) to accomplish this, with the [cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) `background-size`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r23qt8qt/2/)**

In the demo I am using [an image with rectangular dimensions](http://lorempixel.com/400/200/)(`400x200`) but the `div` element has a `height` and `width` of `200px`.

By using the `cover` value you maintain the original aspect ratio of the image and cover the visible area of the element, essentially *cropping* the image.

```css
div {
  background: #2a2828 url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is that this isn't responisve wan't to use percentage values

Comment: @Felix then change the `height` and `width` values to `%`

Comment: @Felix - [updated fiddle with `%`s](https://jsfiddle.net/r23qt8qt/1/)

Comment: tried this but its not a squere --- its a rectangle thats not what I needed.

Comment: @Felix you said you want to use **%** which will adapt to the viewport size,  which will change the aspect ratio - if you **want to keep it square** you need to use media queries and adjust the `height` and `width` at various viewport sizes - **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r23qt8qt/2/)** - you'll have chose if you want to use % and deal with changing aspect ratios or fixed `height` / `width` and adjust at breakpoints - **adjust the viewport when viewing the demo** - you'll need your own breakpoints for your site/app

Comment: is there really no smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: @Felix there is a way ... if you allow me I can close this as duplicate, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37465002/2887133

Comment: @DaniP - that's very similar to the answer I gave - so to answer his question, there is no *smarter* way to do it

Comment: similar but has a huge difference, already answer the question keeping responsive the size of the container and the proportion 1:1 ... You don't need "breakpoints"

Comment: but his version perfectly works! Thanks!

Comment: thats exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to set a fixed width and height and backgroud-size cover.

```
.responsive-image {
    background-size: cover;
    background: url("url_of_the_image") 50% 50% no-repeat scroll transparent;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .responsive-image {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .responsive-image {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about the syntax

Comment: problem is that this isn't responisve wan't to use percentage values

Comment: You can use different media queries. I'll update the answer

Comment: The user will also need to use `background-image`,`background-repeat`, `background-position`, `background-size` as well - or the shorthand `background` property.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that.